# Facebook login via JS-SDK via OAuth will get stuck half-way

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get authenticated for Instagram API. I have a business profile. And I'm trying to authenticate via FB login via the JS SDK:

```
  <p id="profile"></p>
  <script>
    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v19.0'
      });

      FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email'}, (response) => {
              const msg = `Howdy ${response.name}. Your email address: ${response.email}`;
              document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = msg;
             });
        } else { 
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.'); }
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          console.log(response.authResponse);
          alert(`response.authResponse: ${response.authResponse}`);
        }
      });
    };
</script>

<!-- The JS SDK Login Button -->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

I click the button, get redirected at FB, enter `login/pass` in the dialog window, enter 2FA code. And then it'll ALWAYS get stuck on this dialog, on the half-way:

[image: FB Auth dlg]

with this url (modified):

[image: url]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information....');
            FB.api('/me', { fields: 'name, email' }, (response) => {
                const msg = `Howdy ${response.name}. Your email address: ${response.email}`;
                document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = msg;
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    },  { scope: "pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement" };
 I hope I can help you.
```

Comment: what a fисking gibberish. how does that answer my question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).